# Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) Not Appearing in logcat

Tags: android, permissions

Does anyone know how the missing permissions behave and when is it shown in logcat?

I tried removing the INTERNET permission intentionally to trigger this exception, but it's not being triggered at all during httpsURLConnection.connect() below -- what happens is that it goes straight to the finally block.

Initially I thought it's because the permission was granted before and the app/test device remembers it, so I uninstalled the app then reinstalled it but the same thing happens.

Does anyone know what triggered this behavior? Thanks!

**Edit: I have another app (Sunshine app from the Udacity course) where I copied this code from, and that one shows the permission error.**

**Excerpt from my class -- expecting a Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) in the httpsURLConnection.connect() line**

```
public class MovieDBAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Object, List<Movie>> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
        try {

            //create a URL
            URL url = new URL(buildURL(params[0]));
            Log.v(TAG, url.toString());
            httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpsURLConnection.connect();

            //get string input
            InputStream inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                //no input stream, nothing to do
                return null;
            }
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            //if stringBuffer is not null, then prepare the result
            if (stringBuffer != null) {
                return getMovieDataFromJSON(stringBuffer.toString());
            }

            if (httpsURLConnection != null) {
                httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: By any chance, you're running this code in Marshmallow and above?

Comment: @TheAbsurd Actually Nougat. 7.0

Answer (score 0):

For Android M and above, check Android docs..

You don't need to permission access for **normal permissions** 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've updated my question to provide more context -- I have a previous app that has the same code but that one triggers the permission exception that's why I'm confused with this current behavior.

Comment: Did you try Sunshine app on same device? Since the important point is the device version(Android 6 and above).

Comment: Yes, that's my previous app I was testing and the exception is appearing there when I remove the internet permission.

Comment: The only general difference I can observe right now is that in the Sunshine app, I'm executing the Asynctask in a Fragment while in my current app, I'm executing the Asynctask in MainActivity that extended AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

For Marshmallow and above, you would need to request permissions at runtime. Mentioning them in AndroidManifest.xml isn't necessary,

Please refer to the following link,
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've updated my question to provide more context -- I have a previous app that has the same code but that one triggers the permission exception that's why I'm confused with this current behavior.

Answer (score -1):

As for marshmallow and above android has a new run time permission system. You have ask for at run time . Add the following snippet into your class which will help you to ask for run time permission . 
        private int INTERNET_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;

```
   //We are calling this method to check the permission status
    private boolean isInternetnAllowed() {
        //Getting the permission status
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        //If permission is granted returning true
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;

        //If permission is not granted returning false
        return false;
    }

    //Requesting permission
    private void requestInternetPermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }

        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, INTERNET_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if(requestCode == INTERNET_PERMISSION_CODE){

            //If permission is granted
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted for internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this,"Oops you just denied the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then what ever you are doing in `doInBackground` method

do it like this way

```
if(isInternetnAllowed()){
     //do your doInbackground stuff
  }else {
      requestInternetPermission();
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've updated my question to provide more context -- I have a previous app that has the same code but that one triggers the permission exception that's why I'm confused with this current behavior.

Comment: I removed it because I want to see the missing permission exception appear in logcat. However even without it, the exception isn't appearing in logcat.

Comment: so the problem is you can't see the exception in logcat, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126721/discussion-between-karl-jamoralin-and-shuvro).

Comment: not true, Internet is not a dangerous permission. it is granted if it is declared in manifest file.